# Can't access AppStore when connected via 3G

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone

When my iPhone (3GS) is connected via 3G, I can't connect to the AppStore. It just loads a while and then says "Could not connect" and that's that.

When I have a WLAN connection, everything works fine.

This has been like this for quite some time now - it also didn't change after rebooting or updating to new versions of iOS.

What's going wrong there?

Comment: are you able to browse websites on 3G, else your Cellular Data settings might be incorrect (Settings -> General -> Cellular -> Cellular Data Network)

Comment: Yes. I can browse Websites, use apps that need Network connections, send Messages in WhatsApp, everything except accessing the AppStore.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a problem where the App Store was working on Wi-Fi, but not on 3G and 4G networks. I solved it by going into:

**Settings** → **Mobile Data** (also called **Cellular**). Under the heading **Use Mobile Data For**, *enable* **App Store**.